# Using one Property List (.plist) for multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, viewcontroller

Can I , or is it feasible to use one **Property List file** to include data that I have to use in multiple view controllers.?
 The data in my **.plist** file is hierarchically arranged, and as I go down the hierarchy the data at different levels is to be used in different view controllers. The view controllers are embed in a **Navigation Controller**. 
If this is not appropriate, is there a different way ? 
If yes then what all ways are there in which I can do the needful. Thanks for your *time*.

Comment: make a model object that does what you want, and share it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to read the file in every view and update the view controller. Instead of reading the file every time, go for a shared data source which would read content on initializing. You can query this class from different view controller in navigation controller hierarchy to fetch respective data to be displayed in that screen.